# FlowRouter:Kadira Trigger On Page Load

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

I am having a problem with adding the active class on my navbar when the page load. The triggerEnters works when I click the page, but I also want it when the page loads.

Here's my code:

```
var headerRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
    triggersEnter: [activePage]
});

function activePage(){

    var selector = '.nav li a[href="' + FlowRouter.current().path + '"]';
    $('.navbar-nav li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(selector).parent("li").addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only feature you want, you might be interested in the [`zimme:active-route`](https://github.com/zimme/meteor-active-route) package on [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/active-route). Otherwise, it's the template's business, not the router's, to know when it was rendered, so you'll need to attach your code to a template event such as [`onCreated`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created) (assuming you're using Blaze).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I really want. Cheers!